# Uni-directionnal animation

Tags: css, animation, transition, directions

I'm currently using a classic transition on a width change.

```
transition: width 0.6s ease;
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/qzbd8mpc/)

I would like to have an animation which occurs only from left to right, right to left should be instant.

Is it possible to do that in pure CSS (Without removing the class using javascript) ?

Edit: new fiddle to show the good use case.

Comment: Just move the `transition` property setting to the `div:hover` selector. Is that what you are looking for? Basically doing this would say apply transition only on hover-in (expand) but not on hover-out (reduce).

Comment: My example is unvalid. I don't want to react to a mouse hover to have this behaviour. 
The value is modified programmaticaly

Comment: I updated my example, I answered a bit too fast to your comment sorry

Comment: For this new fiddle, you can use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qzbd8mpc/1/). We are adding a `expand` class with the transition property when the box is expanding and removing it after the time-out when the box is collapsing. Does this fully address your need?

Comment: This is not only CSS so no.
But the fact that it is not possible to do so would answer my question.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question. If you want to auto-trigger the expand/reduce behavior without JS then animations (mentioned in the answer below) is your best bet. Transitions would work only when the state changes either by adding/removing class (or) changing properties dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation instead of transition
So you can made it by only using css3
 the css code is given below

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 5s;
}

 /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
     from {width: 100px;}
     to {width: 400px;}
 }

 /* Standard syntax */
 @keyframes myfirst {
        from {width: 100px;}
      to {width: 400px;}
  }
```

in this case you don't need javascript
You can specify when the change will happen in percent, or you can use the keywords "from" and "to" (which represents 0% and 100%).

0% represents the start of the animation, 100% is when the animation is complete.
and when an animation is finished, it changes back to its original style.

Comment: Ok this is interesting, but I the animation should not be automatic.

It is triggered by a value change (it is for a progress bar).

The advanced use case is that. I don't see how I can use animation in that context.